# Can two objects in global scope have the same name?

Tags: c, global-variables

Consider the following snippet:

```
struct foo_struct {
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct foo_struct *foo;
struct foo_struct foo_global;

int foo(int x)
{
  ....
  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   foo = &foo_global;
  ...
}
```

So I have two identifiers but for different objects (is it correct to call a
function an object?).  Is this strictly illegal, or does the standard define such 
case as "undefined behavior". What part of the standard describe this?

Answer (score 3):

I get:

```
a.c:9: error: ‘foo’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
a.c:6: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
```

I very much doubt this is legal. You can disambiguate `foo = &foo_global` because you can't "overwrite" a function, but `void *var = foo` would be ambiguous (is `foo` a function pointer or the `struct foo_struct` pointer?).

Now the standard:

> 6.2.1 §2
>   For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is visible (i.e., can be used) only within a region of program text called its scope. Different entities designated by the same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name spaces. [...]

So the identifiers must have different scopes or different name spaces.

> 6.2.1 §4
>   If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
>   appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope, which
>   terminates at the end of the translation unit. [...]
>
> 6.2.1 §6
>   Two identifiers have the same scope if and only if their scopes terminate at the same
>   point.

These indicate both identifiers have the same scope (file scope), which terminates at the end of the translation unit.

> 6.2.3 §1
>   [...] [T]here are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> - `label names` [...]
> - the `tags` of structures, unions, and enumerations [...]
> - the `members` of structures or unions [...]
> - all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

The name spaces are the same, because both are ordinary identifiers.

Therefore, they have the same scope and the same name space, which doesn't satisfy 6.2.1 §2.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to compile it ?
With gcc, this is not legal and produces *of course* an error

```
error: ‘foo’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
error: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable which type is a pointer to a funcion so when you call it, are you call the function or the function pointed by the variable with the same name? It is ambiguous. I think it's illegal. There is no problem for example in java, because there you can't have a variable that points to a function so the use of the parenthesis disambiguate if you are referring the function or the variable.

```
typedef void (*functiontype)();
functiontype func;

void f1 () {
    ...
}
void func () {
    ...
}
void main() {
    func = &f1;
    func();
}
```